# How to stream map list of array object in kotlin

Tags: arrays, list, kotlin, stream

i'm an newer to kotlin.

I Have a data class called User with three properties name, age and city. And I have a list of

array. I want to map this list of array User to obtain a new list containing the name and the city of the user.

these my code

```
data class User(var name: String, var age: Int, var city: String)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val user1 = User("John", 18, "Paris")
    val user2 = User("Sara", 25, "Tokyo")
    val user3 = User("Dave", 34, "Tunis")
    
    val listOfArrayUser = arrayListOf<User>()

    listOfArrayUser.addAll(listOf(user1, user2, user3))
      
    var myNewList : List<String> = listOfArrayUser.stream().map { ("${it.name}-${it.city}") }.toList()
    
    println( "My new list  : " ) 
    println( myNewList) 

}
```

But i doesn't have the correcdt result. How can i do this please

Comment: What result you get and what do you expext?

Comment: You have just made a significant edit to your original question, making my and Ivo's answer no longer valid. What is your _actual_ code and issue?

Comment: Your edit actually made it function correct, though it is not really conventional to do it like that

Answer (score 1):

(This answer applies to [revision #1 of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/73473972/1) only)

---

You have a nested collection of users, so you need to `map` twice. To avoid ending up with a `List<List<String>>`, Kotlin offers a [`flatMap`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/flat-map.html) method.

Note that `stream()` is from the Java world and not needed in Kotlin. You also don't need to have an `args` parameter in your main method and the `toList()` after the mapping is superfluous as well.

Here is a fixed version of your code:

```
data class User(var name: String, var age: Int, var city: String)

fun main() {
    val user1 = User("John", 18, "Paris")
    val user2 = User("Sara", 25, "Tokyo")
    val user3 = User("Dave", 34, "Tunis")
    
    var listOfArrayUser = listOf<Array<User>>(arrayOf(user1, user2, user3))
      
    var myNewList : List<String> = listOfArrayUser.flatMap { it.map { "${it.name}-${it.city}" } }
    
    println("My new list  : ") 
    println(myNewList) 
}
```

Output:

```
My new list  : 
[John-Paris, Sara-Tokyo, Dave-Tunis]
```

As an additional note: [data classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html) are usually intended to be immutable, so your `User` class should probably look like this (note the `val` instead of `var`):

```
data class User(val name: String, val age: Int, val city: String)
```

Comment: Hi @Marvin I have a question if var listOfArrayUser : List<*> = listOf<Array<User>>(arrayOf(user1, user2, user3)), How Can I map only each element of listOfArrayUser and display it

Comment: I don't understand. How is that different from my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to use a stream for that. You can do

```
var myNewList : List<String> = listOfArrayUser.flatMap { it.toList() }.map { ("${it.name}-${it.city}") }
```

Comment: Hi @Ivo I have a question if var listOfArrayUser : List<*> = listOf<Array<User>>(arrayOf(user1, user2, user3)), How Can I map only each element of listOfArrayUser and display it

Comment: @peace3106 don't write the `: List<*>` part. Leave it out or write it as `: List<Array<User>>`

Comment: i want to say that if i have List<Object[]> and my result is a List<Array<user>> how can i map my List<Array<user>> to doesn't have error kotlin compilation infeereed type by example